Innodb - Can you safely ignore the warning "Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size"
We get this warning in our online shop

report.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more
than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update
innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases
memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 589;
Allocated memory size: 1742262000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size:
8589934592 bytes.

So I ran mysqltuner to analyse the database settings and it recommends to set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to >13.7GB. It is set to 8GB currently.
We expect very high customer traffic on january, so I asked my supervisor if I am allowed to increase the value to about 14 GB (we have 12 GB free RAM), but according to him it is just a warning and we should ignore it until we switch to another hoster in march.
According to my research, this misconfiguration can lead to performance loss and even cause transactions to fail and ulitimately cause bugs. Is this really just a warning that one can ignore?
What is the worst case that can happen when ignored?

Additional Information:
We are using rabbitMQ to import catalog data from a PIM (Product Information Management) system into magento 2. The warning is always appearing, when the queue consumers are running. This slows down the shop and the load average rises to about 30 (10 cpus) during this time, while it is on 6 on average.

mysqltuner is useless, better delete/remove it. See Configuring InnoDB Buffer Pool Size how to properly set innodb_buffer_pool_size

Ok, thank you. My supervisor recommended it. Why do you think that it is useless?

In my opinion and experience it often gives generic recommendation and it does not understand your workload

I also recommending binning mysqltuner. I've seen cases where it confidently makes recommendations that are based on incorrect knowledge of how MySQL works. See for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032405/20860

Use the SlowLog to discover what query is likely to be leading to the warning.  Then post the SHOW CREATE TABLE and the query.

I, too, think the tuner is not very good.  See https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning for what I can do to help with tuning.

The warning you saw is not produced by MySQL Server, it's produced by Magento.
It has to do with "indexing" which is Magento's term for a type of ETL process. Your canonical data is stores in normalized tables, which is good for data integrity and maintenance. Then Magento makes one or more copies of the data in denormalized tables to speed up certain searches or aggregations. This is not uncommon.
The process of copying the data from the normal tables to the denormalized tables uses memory temporarily, and the amount depends on the size of your data sets. If you had millions of products for example like Amazon, it could take a lot of memory, and probably have to do the copying and transforming work in batches.
Magento doesn't necessarily need to reindex the whole collection when you change something simple, like adding one product or changing a price or something. So even if your total catalog is large, it won't necessarily need to use memory of that size every time you change something.
It's not clear to me what, if anything, this has to do with innodb_buffer_pool_size. If Magento is using the MEMORY storage engine for temporary data storage, as the documentation says, this it is not using the InnoDB storage engine for temporary data. No amount of the InnoDB buffer pool is used for tables in the MEMORY storage engine.
So I don't understand why the warning is produced.
I recommend doing what your supervisor told you in this case: ignore the warning for now, until you change your hosting platform.

Re your comment: increasing the load over about 10 is a matter for concern. Until you change hosting platforms to a more powerful server, you should consider slowing down your RabbitMQ consumers, so they load data more gradually and don't cause the spike in load or the slowing of the shop operations.
Or run the import at a time of day or night when there is the least traffic.
Anyway, follow the instructions of your supervisor. If they want to prioritize other work and let the online shop get slow occasionally, that's their decision.

Thank you for your answer! We are using rabbitMQ to import data from a PIM (Product Information Management) system into magento 2. The warning is always appearing, when the queue consumers are running. This slows down the shop and the load average rises to about 30 (10 cpus), while it is on 6 on average. So it is not caused by magento, but by the queue consumers. I will edit my post to add this information.

Is it true that this can lead to failed transactions and data inconsistency, if we are not increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size?

That is not true.
